# Use only alpha channel of texture in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, alphablending

Hey, I'm trying to draw a constant color to the framebuffer and blend it using the alpha channel from an RGBA texture. I've been looking at glBlendFunc and glBlendColor, but can't seem to figure out a way to ignore the RGB values from the texture. I'm thinking I'll have to pull out the alpha values myself and make a second texture with GL_ALPHA. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The best answer is quite simple: Use shaders. In GLSL code you can use the texture data in whatever way you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using colour coded picking. This is the code I'm using so that transparent areas of a textured quad will not be picked:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_ALPHA, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);

glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.5f);

glColor3ub(myColor[0], myColor[1], myColor[2]);

drawTexturedQuad();
```

Essentially I'm saying I want the RGB to be whatever it was before applying the texture (This would be myColor) and I want the ALPHA to be taken from the texture.

Answer (score 0):

When using glBlendFunc, `GL_SRC_ALPHA` and `GL_DST_ALPHA` can be used to select the alpha channel in your texture (which to choose depends on your blend operation and textures). For more detailed blending tutorials see:

- [nehe tutorial #32](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=32)

The relevant OpenGL documentation:

- http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml

Comment: glBlendFunc lets you select different alpha values and how to blend with them, but as far as I know that all affects how you _scale and combine_ the source and destination colors. I'm trying to ignore the source color and blend a different one using only the alpha value from the RGBA texture.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to mask? See the tutorial #3 link for a section on 'mask on picture'. Is this what you are trying to do?